# Get Distinct Term ordered by descending in Nest Elastic Search

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, lucene.net, nest

I'm trying to get Top 10 distinct cars order by CarsSold descending using Nest Elastic Search.

My elastic class looks like:

```
public class Make
{
   public string MakeId {get;set;}
   public string MakeName {get;set;}
   public string Address { get;set;}
   public List<Cars> Models {get;set;}
}

 public class Cars
 {
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public string CarsName {get;set;}
     public int CarsSold {get;set;}
 }
```

I tried using below code but the value are not sorted by CarsSold Descending:

```
var cars = Client.Search<Make>(s => s
                .Size(0)
                .Aggregations(a => a
                    .Terms("unique", t => t
                        .Field(f => f.Models.FirstOrDefault().CarsName)
                        .Size(10)
                        .Aggregations(a2 => a2
                            .Max("authStats", s1 => s1.Field(f => f.Models.FirstOrDefault().CarsSold))
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Well, I tried with Max And Stats both using aggregation.

Answer (score 6):

Anyways found way to do it.
It may help others who are struggling like me:
Done by using below code:

```
var result = Client.Search<Make>(s => s
                .Aggregations(a => a
                    .Terms("unique", te => te
                        .Field("cars.carsName")
                        .Size(10)
                        .OrderDescending("totalCount")
                        .Aggregations(aa => aa
                            .Max("totalCount", ma => ma
                                .Field("cars.carsSold")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```